# python lambda syntax error

Tags: python, lambda

I am learning tensorflow to build a neural network, and I have an example code down below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# get weight of a layer, and add the l2 regularizer of the weight to the collection of 'losses'
def get_weight(shape, lambda):
    var = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape), dtype = tf.float32)
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(lambda)(var))
    return var
```

I use python 3.5 to run this script, but I get this:

```
  File "4.4.2.py", line 4
    def get_weight(shape, lambda):
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `lambda` is a keyword in python. You'll have to choose a different variable name.

Comment: `lambda` is a reserved word in python you shouldn't use it as a parameter name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda` is a reserved word in python, and it shouldn't be used as a parameter/variable name. This goes the same with all other [reserved words](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass parameter to function using python `lambda` keyword. It can't be done. Replace `lambda` with something else.

Answer (score 1):

You should use _lambda rather than **lambda** variable ,as lambda is reserved keyword. generally _ attached to keyword to remove conflict between reserved keyword and variable.